# ML project in android app using Tensorflowlite

Tags: android, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-lite

I have a model file in tensorflow. I have to integrate in Android application and build a sample app. The model takes in tokenised input. (number array instead of sentences). The application takes sentence input from user. What should be done to implement the tokeniser too in Java android application if the tensorflow model is in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find some reusable code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples
May be in the bert_qa example? https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/bert_qa/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/bertqa/tokenization